# Форматирование String в C#

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

Пытаюсь сделать тест, который будет проверять сортировку цен в Steam. Тест вбивает определённое название игры в поиск, сортирует по убыванию цены, а дальше проверяет правильность порядка отсортированных игр по цене. Я достаю цену каждой игры в `string`, но если у игры есть скидка, то получаю что - то в духе `"15150 pуб.\r\n12058,10 pуб."`.
Интересует, можно ли отформатировать этот string так, чтобы убрать старую цену слева и оставить только актуальную цену справа.
Сортируется не вся страница, а только 10 первых результатов.
Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно, стоит глянуть в сторону регулярных выражений, выделить цены и найти наименьшую...

Comment: Вопрос слишком расплывчато сформулирован, чтобы можно было конкретно ответить. Приведите исходный код сайта для блока с ценой но без скидки, затем блок с ценой и со скидкой, а также покажите код, которым вы узнаёте цену.

Comment: `string price = input.Split("\r\n")[1];`

Comment: @aepot Split работает как нужно, если игра со скидкой, но при этом даёт ошибку на тех играх, где нет скидки и нет необходимости использовать Split

Comment: Ну так проверяйте сколько элементов получается после split

Comment: @AK Узнаю цены с помощью `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//*[contains(@class,'col search_price') and not(contains(@class,'combined'))])")).Text` на странице выдачи по поиску. `<div class="col search_price  responsive_secondrow"> 22601,70 pуб.</div>` - блок без скидки. `<div class="col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow"><span style="color: #888888;"><strike>40629 pуб.</strike></span><br>35361 pуб.</div>` - блок со скидкой.

Comment: `string price = input.Split("\r\n").Last()`

Comment: @CrazyElf Не до конца понимаю. У меня цены цепляются все вместе без разделения на цены со скидкой и без скидки.

Comment: @KuzCode Да! Спасибо большое, так работает правильно.

Comment: `string price = input.Split("\r\n")[^1];`

Comment: Для начала, у Steam есть простой API, который без труда скажет вам нужный ценник, любой игры и даже парсить не надо что-либо, зачем вообще вам тут селениум? Далее, если вы парсите HTML, то делайте это правильно, ибо `"15150 pуб.\r\n12058,10 pуб."` явно говорит о том, что вы берете текст, а не разбиваете HTML, даже вон выше, в вашем комментарии видно 3 цены, где каждая лежит в своем теге, так почему не брать их?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Такое задание дали на курсах, надо именно на селениуме. А из того, как и откуда всё брать, то у меня практически минимальные знания в XPath и это мой предел на текущий момент, иначе не придумал.

Comment: Такие штуки через селениум просто сложно делать и медленно работают. Апишечка когда она есть - идеальное решение. Когда нет - связка `HttpClient`+`HtmlAgilityPack` хорошо работает. Селениум для автоматического тестирования больше подходит, но никак не для парсинга.